# Can't read the file with BufferedReader

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to read a file from the assets folder in my Android project but can't make it work. I'm trying something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView fileContentTextView;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fileContentTextView = findViewById(R.id.file_content_textview);

        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                AssetManager assetManager = getBaseContext().getAssets();
                try {
                    InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("cos.txt");
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                    String str;
                    str = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    stringBuilder.append(str);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        Log.d("ECG", stringBuilder.toString());
        String textToShow = stringBuilder.toString();
        fileContentTextView.setText(textToShow);
    }
}
```

But nothing shows up in the log or when trying to setText. Don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you debug into it?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking about

Comment: `AsyncTask.execute()` schedules work to be done in a background thread. However, you are trying to use `stringBuilder` right away. The results will not be ready yet. If you are going to use the old `AsyncTask` approach, you might want to [follow the patterns shown in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask).

Comment: Thanks,I understand my mistake now.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you need to use AsyncTask.execute(). As explained by CommonsWare's comment, it executes in a background thread (separate from the main UI thread). Thus, stringbuilder.append(str) is being called later whereas `Log.d("ECG", stringBuilder.toString());   String textToShow = stringBuilder.toString(); fileContentTextView.setText(textToShow);` are being called sooner.

There are thus, two ways to correct this:

1. Remove the code from AsysncTask.execute() as shown:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView fileContentTextView;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fileContentTextView = findViewById(R.id.file_content_textview);

        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();


        AssetManager assetManager = getBaseContext().getAssets();
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("cos.txt");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String str;
            str = bufferedReader.readLine();
            stringBuilder.append(str);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d("ECG", stringBuilder.toString());
        String textToShow = stringBuilder.toString();
        fileContentTextView.setText(textToShow);
    }
}
```

2. Put the log.d and fileContentTextView.setText(textToShow); inside the AsyncTask.execute()

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView fileContentTextView;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        fileContentTextView = findViewById(R.id.file_content_textview);

        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                AssetManager assetManager = getBaseContext().getAssets();
                try {
                    InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("cos.txt");
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                    String str;
                    str = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    stringBuilder.append(str);
                    Log.d("ECG", stringBuilder.toString());
                    String textToShow = stringBuilder.toString();
                    fileContentTextView.setText(textToShow);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I have tested both and they have worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, I already figured it out by myself and put it inside the AsyncTask.execute() as in your second example.